# Hibernate mapping annotation skipped by the system

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have an issue with the mapping under hibernate. I have an abstract class which implements an interface:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractPromotion implements IPromotion {
}
```

This abstract class is the super class(as you can see with the annotation) and 3 mapped classes with `@Entity` extend this super class. When i launch a "maven install" i get this failure message inside the console , it says :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: product.model.Product.promotion[product.promotion.AbstractPromotion]
```

i don't understand it because the class in question is mapped (as the classes which extend it) as above but it's like the annotations are skipped...
any help would be really appreciated

best regards

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractPromotion` is not an entity. Its a `MappedSuperclass`. To apply an inheritance strategy, and to be the target of an association, a class must be an entity. Replace `@MappedSuperclass` by `@Entity`.

Mappedsuperclass is only used to be able to inherit common fields and methods in several, unrelated entities (like, for example, inherit an `id`, or a `creationDate`, in several unrelated entities).

Answer (score 0):

If you want share the same database table for all the sublcass you need use discriminators.
In the main class you need to add this annotations.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "foo")
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
  @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "foo_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
```

And in the subclass this annotation

```
       @Entity
       @DiscriminatorValue("The value of your foo_type that discriminate this entity")
```